# Make a Bootstrap popover modal?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, popover

I show a popover manually in javascript but for added emphasis I'd like to make it modal i.e. disable background functionality and fade. Is there an option to do this or how would I go about it manually?

I know it's mixing design metaphors but it would be useful functionality and I can't see restyling modals to adapt to relative positioning being easy.

Comment: Pretty sure this is not possible with an option. Manually, you want to create a `div` that sits over the entire contents of your page. Its `z-index` wants to be less than the popover and greater than the rest of the page. Have a go!

Comment: Here's a jsFiddle to get you started: http://jsfiddle.net/cMxYd/

Answer (score 3):

take a look at this script, i think this should help u

http://scruffles.github.io/BootstrapModalPopover/

Answer (score 2):

add

```
.popover, .tooltip {
    z-index: 1060 !important;
}
```

to your styles

Comment: I found in bootstrap 3 that the z-index had to be over 2000.